# How can I take backup of Visual Studio 2013 with SP4 from current installed OS before formatting system?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Is there any way to take visual studio 2013 back with SP4 before system formatting ?
Because each time i have to download SP4  for visual studio 2013 and its time consuming. So please is there any way to take back up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot, you could create a local copy of all the installer files using the `/layout` option of the `vs_edition.exe`:

```
vs_ultimate.exe /layout
```

Then backup that for future installations.

Or you can download the installer that was updated to **include** update 4 from the [MSDN subscription site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/securedownloads/?#searchTerm=Visual%20Studio%202013%20with%20Update%204&ProductFamilyId=0&Languages=en&PageSize=10&PageIndex=0&FileId=0) or from [VisualStudio.com, pick the DVD9 ISO download](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs) option. If you download the Trial version you can also activate that using your product key.